# Merging two files based on matching columns with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two text files with the following structures:

- File 1:

  ```
  File/Path/DataXXX File/Path/ImageXXX
  ```
- File 2:

  ```
  1 File/Path/ImageXXX DataGroupXXX
  ```

In file 2 the first column in every row has been replaced with a 1 as a dummy column to be replaced. I want to use `awk` to match column 2 in file 1 with column 2 in file 2, and then replace the dummy column 1 in file 2 with the matching datapath in column 1 from file 1. This will associate `DataXXX` with its corresponding `ImageXXX` and `DataGroupXXX` in file 2.

My command looks like this:

```shell
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$2;next}($1 in a) {$1= a[$1]}2' File1.txt File2.txt > mergedfile.txt
```

I can't get this to work, I have tried changing the numbers around a bit but I think I am misunderstanding the syntax of the command and it doesn't make the change I want. Does anyone see a problem with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} ($2 in a) {$1 = a[$2]} 1' File1.txt File2.txt` presumably

Comment: @steeldriver thank you, this works!